# Faster way to color format text in a RTB

Tags: vb.net, colors, richtextbox

I am writing a program, to read a log out to the screen, from a remote server.

the Program adds 1 line to the bottom for each new package is recieves.

Currently i am using a TextBox for the speed, as i get about 600-2200 packages each minutes, and the RTB simply can't follow.

i remove the top line, when the lines[] exceeds 300 lines, to reduce memory usage, and speed reduction.

Problem is i really want the lines color formatted, so its easier to see what it outputs, as the stream goes too fast for most human eyes.

as fare as i know, there is only the Select methode to color text in RTB, however i was wondering, if there was any component that is better to use, then the standart RTB, that was more reliable, then the RTB?

Comment: No human can read 37 messages per second, it just looks like a blur.  Trying to make it faster is pointless, it will be just more blurry and less usable.  Create a *practical* user interface and your RTB problem disappears as well.

Comment: you might be right.. i have been to lazy to see the need for a new GUI.

main problem is... the Protocol i am reading the remote logs from, have past 1000 diffrent Packages, and i have only identified and successfully pharsed 60 of them.. the rest is getting read by a raw byte to ascii reader.
the main reason i currently use the textbox, is for me to get an idea of what the program is doing with the data, and how i should continue to read them.
However i should proberly start to write them to file-logs instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to have an intermediate buffer (queue) to store the information gathered from the packages.

```
Dim _buffer as New List(Of String)
```

When a new package arrives add it to the end of the buffer:

```
_buffer.Add("package contents")
```

Then you could use a timer to read out the contents of the buffer every half a second and colourize the textbox.

```
Private Event Timer_Tick 
    Do Until _buffer.Count = 0
        rtb.Text += _buffer(0)
        'colourise the textbox
        _buffer.RemoveAt(0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

You may run into problems reading and writing to the buffer on separate threads in which case you could try using [SyncLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but this may get you going for now

Comment: this and a way to use suspendlayout and resumelayout might be handy :)